# My nested for loop does not work with my csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

My row for loop runs once and then stops. I really do not understand what is going on. The program is supposed to run for the amount of inputs there are in t, but it doesn't. (Note: The names are split by \n)

I literally cannot think of a way to make this work.

## Python File

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import csv
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
class CLabel(Label):
    bgcolor = ListProperty([0,0,0])


class Cp(Screen):

    def signin(self):
        pop = Popup(title='Custom Hours',
                    content=Label(text='Hours Added'),
                    size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 200))
        pop.open()

    def noUser(self, t):

        content = Label(text='Users: {x} Not Found'.format(x = t))
        pop = Popup(title='Custom Hours',
                    content=content,
                    size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 200))
        pop.open()


   
    def check_tutor(self, text1):
        t = text1.split('\n')
        temp = []


        tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False)

        name_d = False
        sheetrow = 0

        with open('D:\\johnp\\kivy_venv\\tsting\\test.csv', 'r') as fh, tempfile:

            head = {'Position': 'Position', 'Name': 'Name', 'Grade': 'Grade',
                    'School': 'School', 'Tutor\'s Phone': 'Tutor\'s Phone',
                    'Tutor\'s Email': 'Tutor\'s Email', 'Parent\'s Phone': 'Parent\'s Phone',
                    'Parent\'s Email': 'Parent\'s Email', 'Hours': 'Hours'}

            reader = csv.reader(fh)
            headers = next(reader)

            reader1 = csv.DictReader(fh, fieldnames=headers)
            writer = csv.DictWriter(tempfile, fieldnames=headers)
            writer.writerow(head)



            #this is the part I help on
            for item in t:
                for row in reader1:
                    sheetrow += 1
                    if row['Name'] == item.strip():
                        name_d = True
                        try:
                            row['Hours'] = float(row['Hours']) + 0.5
                            self.signin()
                        except ValueError:
                            invalidForm()

                    row = {'Position': row['Position'], 'Name': row['Name'], 'Grade': row['Grade'],
                           'School': row['School'], 'Tutor\'s Phone': row['Tutor\'s Phone'],
                           'Tutor\'s Email': row['Tutor\'s Email'], 'Parent\'s Phone': row['Parent\'s Phone'],
                           'Parent\'s Email': row['Parent\'s Email'], 'Hours': row['Hours']}

                    writer.writerow(row)
                if row['Name'] != item.strip():
                    temp.append(item)

            if name_d == False:
                self.noUser(temp)

        shutil.move(tempfile.name, 'D:\\johnp\\kivy_venv\\tsting\\test.csv')


def invalidForm():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Form',
                content=Label(text='Please fill in all inputs with valid information.'),
                size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()





class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass



kv = Builder.load_file("my1.kv")

sm = WindowManager()

screens = [Cp(name="cp")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "cp"


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

## Kv File

```
<WindowManager>:
    Cp:


<Cp>:
    name: "cp"
    GridLayout:

        cols: 1
        size: root.width/2, root.height/2

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            CLabel:
                text: "Enter Names: "
                color: 0,0,0,1
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1, 1, 0, 1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

            TextInput:
                id: x
                multiline:  True


        Button:
            text: "Add Clean Up Hours"
            on_release:
                root.check_tutor(x.text)

        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "other"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

## csv File

```
Position,Name,Grade,School,Tutor's Phone,Tutor's Email,Parent's Phone,Parent's Email,Hours

Tutor,Bob 1,9,asdasd,123123,sadadds,122112313,3123213213,0.0

Tutor,Bob 2,9,asdasd,123123,sadadds,122112313,3123213213,0.0

Tutor,Bob 3,9,asdasd,123123,sadadds,122112313,3123213213,0.0
```

Edit: I added all the necessary code needed to reproduce this problem. Please help. Thank You.

Comment: Can you please show what `t` and `reader1` are? And how do you know it doesn't run for that long? What happens?

Comment: Also, I don't think you should be rewriting `row` while you are iterating through it..

Comment: instead of `for i in range(len(t)):`  you can use `for item in t:` and then you can use `item` instead of `t[i]`

Comment: updated the code for you

Comment: I changed it, but I think it did the same thing.

Comment: @John provide a [mre]

Comment: @John Your code is not complete enough for us to understand, please provide a code that is comprehensive enough to understand.

Comment: What does your code actually output?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 It outputs all the names that you input, but its suppose to only list the names that are not on the list